# If the areas of the rectangle and triangle are equal, find the value of h.

Tags: geometry

A rectangle and triangle are inscribed in a circle of radius $1$. The length of the base of the triangle is the same as the length of the base of the rectangle. If the areas of the rectangle and triangle are equal, find the value of h.

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iamAP.png)

to my understanding, it is basically saying:

$\frac{1}{2} b h=bh$

but i can't really solve that.

Any other interpretations?

Comment: Assume the triangle is isosceles to get $h_{max}$ then there will be scalene triangles that satisfy the equal area condition whenever $h<h_{max}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possible values of $h$, unless we specify that the triangle is isosceles, as it kind of looks in the picture. Then $h$ is determined.

Your puzzlement comes from assuming that the height of the triangle is $h$. The problem does not say it is. And as you point out, it cannot be. The area condition forces it to be $2h$.  That should be a good start towards solving the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure but how would it help if the triangle is isosceles?

Comment: Suppose the arrangement is as in the picture, with the triangle isosceles. Let $O$ be the centre of the circle, and let $P$ be the top vertex of the isosceles triangle. Join $OP$, and let it meet the top edge of the rectangle at $Q$. Note that $OQ=h/2$ and $OP=1$. So $QP=1-h//2$. This is the height of the triangle. As we saw in the answer, this height is $2h$. So $1-h/2=2h$, and therefore $h=2/5$.

Comment: Oh! Im beginning to see it, but how did you know  $QP=1-\frac{h}{2}$

Comment: The height of the rectangle is $h$. So the distance $OQ$ from the centre of the circle, which is also the centre of the rectangle, to the top horizontal line of the rectangle, is half of $h$, so $h/2$. The distance $OP$ is the radius of the circle, so $OP=1$. And $QP=OP-OQ=1-h/2$.

Comment: You are welcome. By the way, if we change the picture and make the triangle point *downwards* we get another value of $h$ that works. But I assume the picture came with the problem.